# How do I delete Signing Identities in Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode5, code-signing

In Xcode, I can go to: Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > View Details...

I then see **Signing Identities** on top, and **Provisioning Profiles** on the bottom.

Under Signing Identities, I see two identities "iOS Development (2)" and "iOS Distribution" how do I delete these so that I can recreate them?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to delete them by launching Keychain Access, and deleting the Certificates and Keys associated with those Signing Identities, then relaunching the Xcode Preferences window. You can easily find the associated entries by searching for "iOS" in Keychain Access.

Note: the "iOS Development (2)" still appeared there, but after creating a new one using the plus button, it replaced that old one.